# Demographic Database or API

Tags: database, api, marketing

Does anyone have a recommendation on a demographic database or API?  I have found one here http://demographicmarketing.net but I was looking for more options. I like that they have a lat/long and IP Address lookup built into the API.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/) & [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass7/) for a number of APIs for accessing geographic based data and some of the data sources listed [here](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Public_Geospatial_Data_Project#Geo_Data_Repositories_.2F_Group_Collection_Projects) for a number of gratis data sources including demographic information.  There is also a very nice tutorial [here](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/08/interactive-data-visualization-geospatial-d3-dc-leaflet-python/) on accessing geographic demographic data.